# How to: Set collision for ray sensor, but not for chassis

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I would like to define models, which can be sensed by the ray sensor, but can not collide with each other.

A simple example is attached.
Here I want to sense permanently the corner of the red Object, while I am driving **through** the object.
Now the problem appears, if I set the collision parameter of the red object.
If they are `<pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>`, the robot can drive through the object, but the ray sensor can not sense it.
On the other hand, if I set the collision to the same values as the visual parameters, the ray sensor can sense to corners, but the robot can not drive through.

[image: Corners can be detected]
[image: Robot can drive through, but corners can not be detected]

How can I set the right parameters, to sense the corners and dirve through an object?

Kind regards,
tik0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8040/how-to:-set-collision-for-ray-sensor,-but-not-for-chassis/) by [tik0](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1100/tik0/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

there is a tag called [`<collide_without_contact>`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision#contact_collide_without_contact) , set it to true for your collision.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1100/tik0/) on 2015-02-19**:
You made my day! It works like a charm. In addition, I had to set the model parameter of the red box to true.